# Code not reading or basically skipping my exception (Jgrasp)

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to make my class and exception to run with my driver class but it seems my  class is not taking the exceptions from that class to my driver

someone had the similar problem and posted that changing the constructor from

```
this.title = title;
this.isbn = isbn;
this.quantity = quantity;
```

to

```
setTitle(title);
setIsbn(isbn);
setQuantity(quantity);
```

would fix it but I am getting an error on my book class

Bookstore2

```
public class Bookstore2{

     //this program will read the information for one book
     //it will validate it and print it if correct

   public static void main(String arg[ ]) throws Exception{

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int size = 3;
     int isbn=0;
     int quantity = 0;
     String title = "";
     int count=0;
     boolean exit = false;
     Book oneBook;

     try{
        System.out.print("Enter title: ");
        title = sc.nextLine( );
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter isbn: ");
        isbn = sc.nextInt( );
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
        quantity = sc.nextInt( );
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        oneBook = new Book(title, isbn, quantity);  //attempting to create the book
                  //if any information about the book is inconsistent the BookExcpetion will be
                  //thrown by the Book constructor/set methods and it should be caught
        System.out.println("The book entered was:");
        System.out.println(oneBook.toString( ));
     }

     catch(InputMismatchException ime){
        System.out.println("you did not enter a number");
     }
     catch (BookException be){
        System.out.println(be.getMessage( ));  //calling the getMessage from BookException.java
     }  

   }  //main method
}   //class
```

Book

```
public class Book{
//instance variables
private String title = "";
private int isbn;
private int quantity;

public Book (String title, int isbn, int quantity)throws BookException{     
//constructors

     setTitle(title);
     setIsbn(isbn);
     setQuantity(quantity);

   }
public String toString( ){ //toString Method

    String s = "";
    s = s + "Title: " + this.title + "\nISBN: " + this.isbn +   "\nQuantity: " + this.quantity + "\n";
    return s;

    }

public String getTitle( ){
    return this.title;
    }
public int getisbn( ){
    return this.isbn;
    }
public int getquantity( ){  
    return this.quantity;
    }

//mutator methods
public void settitle(String newtitle )throws BookException{
    if(newtitle.length()<1){
    BookException be = new BookException( );
    be.setMessage("Title cannot be blank");
    throw be;
    }
    else{
    this.title=newtitle;
    }
}

public void setisbn(int newisbn)throws BookException{
    if(newisbn>=1000 && newisbn>=10000){
    this.isbn = newisbn;
    }
    else{
    BookException be = new BookException( );
    be.setMessage("ISBN should be between 1000 and 10000.");
    throw be;
    }
}

public void setquantity(int newquantity)throws BookException{
   if(newquantity>=0){
   this.quantity = newquantity;
    }
   else{
    BookException be = new BookException( );
    be.setMessage("Quantity can't be a negative number.");
    throw be;
     }
  }

}
```

BookException

```
public class BookException extends Exception {
    //instance variable
    private String message = "";

    public void setMessage(String newMessage) {
        this.message = newMessage;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

Here is the error

```
Book.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
     setTitle(title);
     ^
  symbol:   method setTitle(String)
  location: class Book
Book.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
     setIsbn(isbn);
     ^
  symbol:   method setIsbn(int)
  location: class Book
Book.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
     setQuantity(quantity);
     ^
  symbol:   method setQuantity(int)
  location: class Book
3 errors
```

Comment: methods names are in lowercase in `Book`.

Comment: jesus! thanks now it works but it's not taking the exceptions for some reason

Comment: getting some weird problems on this field   : public void setIsbn(int newisbn)throws BookException{
    if(newisbn>=1000 && newisbn>=10000){
    this.isbn = newisbn;
    }
    else{
    BookException be = new BookException( );
    be.setMessage("ISBN should be between 1000 and 10000.");
    throw be;
    }

Comment: if i put 1000 and such or even a negative quantity,, it should error out that it can't be negative but the "the isbn should be between 1000 to 1000" error message shows up instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

```
 setTitle(title);
 setIsbn(isbn);
 setQuantity(quantity);
```

use

```
 settitle(title);
 setisbn(isbn);
 setquantity(quantity);
```

Since all the methods names are in lowercase in `Book` class.

Comment: thank you very much! although i'm having problems on one of my exceptions

Comment: if i put 1000 and such or even a negative quantity,, it should error out that it can't be negative but the "the isbn should be between 1000 to 1000" error message shows up instead ......